# how to test radio button in react testing library(User can select other radio button)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am new to react and writing test case in react. I have two radio buttons (IPV4 and IPV6). I want to test that a user can select another radio button or not. I don't know which event listener to apply on radio button, is it change event or click event?

I broke down my problem into two parts: 1) I am checking whether I can select or deselect one radio button or not 2) I can select another radio button or not. I failed in my 1 part only so please help me. Here is my code and test case.

```js
import React from 'react'    
import constants from 'LookingGlass/constants'    
import { Label, RadioButton } from 'LookingGlass/common/components'
    
export const componentTestId = 'SelectorIPVersion'
    
export default function SelectorIPVersion(props = {}) {
    const { checkedVersion, onChange, disabled } = props
    
    const { choices, groupName, label } = constants.SelectorIPVersion
    
    const _onChange = (e) => {
        onChange && onChange(e.target.value)
    }
    
    let selectorChoices = choices.map((c) => {
        return (
            <RadioButton
                key={c.value}
                id={c.value}
                name={groupName}
                value={c.value}
                label={c.label}
                checked={c.value === checkedVersion}
                onChange={_onChange}
                disabled={disabled}
            />
        )
    })
    
    return (
        <div data-testid={componentTestId}>
            <Label text={label} />
    
            {selectorChoices}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is my test case:
Here i am trying select and deselect the radio button but this is giving me error so how can I check that user can select another option or not?

```js
const renderComponent = (props) => render(<SelectorIPVersion {...props} />)

test('Verify that user can select another version', () => {
    const { getByRole, debug } = renderComponent({ checkedVersion: 'ipv4' })
    
    const radio = getByRole('radio', { name: 'IPv4' })
    expect(radio).toBeChecked()
    debug(radio)
    fireEvent.click(radio)
    expect(radio).not.toBeChecked()      
})
```

Output of Error:

```
Received element is  checked:
      <input class="hidden" id="ipv4" name="ipVersion" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="radio" value="ipv4" checked=""/>
```

When I debug the IPV4 radio button this is the output:
● Console

```
console.log node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:94
  <input
    checked=""
    class="hidden"
    id="ipv4"
    name="ipVersion"
    readonly=""
    tabindex="0"
    type="radio"
    value="ipv4"
  />
```

And when I don't pass checkedVersion: 'ipv4' as props radio button is not checked.

Where am I wrong. Is it right or wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify what are you trying to test? Why are you triggering a `fireEvent.change` on the `IPv4` radio button?

Comment: i want to test radio buttons (IPv4 and IPv6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Radio buttons are meant to be used in groups, so that when clicking on one of them deselects the currently selected one. To test that a radio button is deselected simply select the other one.

```js
test('Verify that user can select another version', () => {
    const { getByRole } = renderComponent({ checkedVersion: 'ipv4' })
    const ipv4Radio = getByRole('radio', { name: 'IPv4' })
    const ipv6Radio = getByRole('radio', { name: 'IPv6' })
    expect(ipv4Radio).toBeChecked()
    fireEvent.click(ipv6Radio)
    expect(ipv4Radio).not.toBeChecked() 
    expect(ipv6Radio).toBeChecked()     
})
```

However, as a test this doesn't bring much value since you're just testing that radio buttons work as expected (we already know they do). You should focus on testing your own logic around these buttons instead.

Comment: I tired this but giving error:  expect(element).not.toBeChecked()

    Received element is checked:
      <input checked="" class="hidden" id="ipv4" name="ipVersion" readonly="" tabindex="0" type="radio" value="ipv4" />

Comment: Are you certain you are firing the click event on the unselected radio (the IPv6 radio, in this case)?

Comment: Not really related to the issue, but I want to point out that radio buttons are supposed to have the same name (but different values). That's the point with the radio buttons: they have to belong to the same group, and only one will be checked at a time.